# How to change the variable which contains a path string to another path string

Tags: shell, variables

These days I have been confused by the shell variable mechanisms.In brief, I plan to  write a shell function which aims to search a target directory with 3 hierarchies bottom-up scan from current path, and returns instantly after the function has encountered target directory. However, I was tripped in the problem that I can't change the variable, containing the a path string, to another path string.

**For Example**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmppath=.

${tmppath}=`pwd`
```

These script goes error.

```bash
./VariableWithPath.sh:5: no such file or directory: .=/mnt/D/Developer/WorkPlace/Personal-Workplace-Temp/shell
```

Why? The variables are used to store some stuffs and can be changed after that, no? If anyone can give me a explanation, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you think `tmppath=...` and `${tmppath}=...` would do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. the tmppath=... and ${tmppath}=... do different things. Whereas, I mixed it with the another language's syntax, such as php, since I made such inferior error. that's too ashamed. haha. Anyway, you have solved my problems, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double-quote words in `bash`, to prevent the shell from spitting it as separate words. I think you need something like

```
tmppath="/some/random/path"
printf "%s\n" "$tmppath"
/some/random/path
```

Replace the variable as below, command-substitution using `` is outdated, use `$(..)`

```
tmppath="${PWD}"
printf "%s\n" "$tmppath"
/Users/name/your-current-path
```

What your incorrect syntax is trying to do is expand `tmppath` in your shell (`.`) and append `=` with the expanded value of `pwd` which becomes

```
.=/mnt/D/Developer/WorkPlace/Personal-Workplace-Temp/shell
```

The reason for the error is the shell tries to treat anything after `.` as an executable file and runs it in the current shell and throws up that such a file did not exist.

Comment: Technically, there is no need to double quote in an assignment with only a single expansion: In `name=$foo`, the expansion of `$foo` is not subject to word-splitting.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I know what is lay with now.

Comment: After acctepted the @Jens advice, this code block `tmppath=.;tmppath=$(pwd);echo $tmppath` solved my problem.